# Render cube map

Tags: rendering

I was trying to create a cube map from a simple scene following [this thread](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?241187-Rendering-a-cubemap-skybox) I found.

The resulting cube map looks like

[image]

the problem is that the black parts on the image should be replaced by a checkerboard plane present in the scene. However, I don't know what am I missing.

I have uploaded my blender file [here](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34091)

Comment: I get this when I just open the file and hit Render without changing anything. http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=82993

Comment: You're not supposed to render it according to the BA thread.

Comment: @SixthOfFour when you render it, if you select the cube and then go to textures, under Environment Map -> next to the[Static | Animation | Image File] there is a black arrow where you can save the environment map and you should get a file similar to mine

Comment: @VinceScalia, then how should I render it?

Comment: It says you're supposed to full render bake it. Also looks like you didn't disable secularity.